# Xamarin Forms: App is always restarting when resuming from background

Tags: xamarin.forms, splash-screen

The `datepicker` UI is breaking and it is showing on top of the splash screen background like below:

[image]

**Code:**

```
<DatePicker
    x:Name="startdate_datepicker"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Format="MM/dd/yyyy"
    PropertyChanged="StartDateChoosed"
    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="Center"/>
```

**My Style:**

```
<style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#e6e6e6</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#808080</item>
```

For solving this issue I made some updates on `Style` and `MainActivity`.

Created a new style for splash:

```
<style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#e6e6e6</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#808080</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.Main" parent ="MainTheme.Base">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#e6e6e6</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#808080</item>
</style>
```

**MainActivity:**

```
[Activity(
    Label = "App Name", 
    Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Main", 
    Icon = "@drawable/launcher_icon", 
    MainLauncher = false,
    NoHistory = true,
    Exported =true,
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, 
    ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]

public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    }
}

[Activity(
        Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash",
        MainLauncher = true,
        NoHistory = true,
        ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        var startUp = new Task(() =>
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            StartActivity(intent);
        });
        startUp.ContinueWith(t => Finish());
        startUp.Start();
    }
}
```

But now my app is always restarting when resuming from background due to the `OnResume()` code in `SplashActivity`. I need to stay on the same page if I resume from background. For that What change I need to do on `SplashActivity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by recreating the `MainActivity` when calling the resume method when restoring the app from the background.

```
[Activity(Label = "Mobile App",
        Theme = "@style/Your_Splash_Theme",
        Icon = "@drawable/Your_Icon",
        MainLauncher = true,
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation,
        LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop)]

public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.ActionBar);
        // Name of the MainActivity theme you had there before.
        base.SetTheme(Resource.Style.MainTheme);
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
// other methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Xamarin.Forms documentation on app lifecycle methods, you can use the `OnSleep` and `OnResume` methods

- OnSleep - called each time the application goes to the background.
- OnResume - called when the application is resumed, after being sent
  to the background.

Here is the demo you can refer to:

```
protected override void OnSleep()
{
    // Save the current page state
    var currentPage = Application.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage;
    var state = currentPage.CurrentPage.BindingContext;
    Application.Current.Properties["CurrentPageState"] = state;
}

protected override void OnResume()
{
    // Retrieve the saved page state and set the page properties
    if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("CurrentPageState"))
    {
        var state = Application.Current.Properties["CurrentPageState"];
        var currentPage = Application.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage;
        currentPage.CurrentPage.BindingContext = state;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added it on the App.xaml.cs, but no luck.

Comment: I have added `OnResume()` on `SplashActivity`, so only by adding `OnSleep` and `OnResume`  on `App.xaml.cs`, how it will work?

Comment: Doesn't `App.xaml.cs`'s `OnResume` get called, when the SplashActivity is done and the main app code starts? You probably also need to add code (and serialization attributes) to "serialize" BindingContext, to store in CurrentPageState, and "deserialize" when restore.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I didn't get you, can you post it as your answer?

Comment: First step, is to implement Guangyu's answer, by adding those methods to application (not to splash screen). Run, what happens? Put breakpoints at start of both those methods, to see if they run at expected times. Then put breakpoint in OnResume on line `var state = ...`. Is that reached when app restarts?

Comment: I have created a demo project with this issue. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fRa8c4trFmbvgUWqQ6QhdhANTh6ZmA-Y/view?usp=sharing Could you please check?

Comment: Install the app and open it, then put it to background. Then open it from background, then the app will restart.

Comment: I faced same problem with @SreejithSree and I tried your solution but it didn't work for me. Do you have any other solution ?